# Team of sales reps all under plan, I'm the only one put on a PIP

Tags: rights

Title says it all. My team is part of an emerging market and we all had a rough year. We were all under plan, but I wasn't last on team. For some reason, I was the only one put on a PIP by my manager. What should I do? What rights do I have?

Comment: How do you know you're the only one under a PIP? Other people might not want to reveal to you that they are under PIP

Comment: What rights you have depend on your location. In the US for instance, discrimination isn't illegal unless it's because of a protected status or class. So it would be perfectly legal to put you on a PIP just because the manager didn't like your color of shoes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ask your manager why.  Without any other input it's hard to tell why.  It could be discrimination or prejudice or that you really did something different than the rest that caused you to be put on a PIP.  Privately ask him why you were singled out of the team when everyone was performing below the mark.